# In what cases would you use a process monitor instead of a try catch around a function

Tags: erlang

I know supervisors can monitor many processes and OTP supervisors provide nice defaults like if there's too many errors in X time then don't retry.

My question is when do you personally choose try catch over a process monitor.

Answer (score 2):

The tools you are speaking of have two completely different use cases.

You should only run things in a process that needs to happen in parallel with something else. Therefore, I would argue that you should use try/catch when you need to catch errors in a situation when you are fine waiting for the result (i.e. a sequential program). You should use an external process for when you need to run something in parallel, and you should monitor it if you are interested in exceptions happening in that process.

That being said, there are of course edge cases where externalizing an activity into a process makes some sense, like special garbage collection corner cases for example (it is sometimes easier/faster to garbage collect an activity by just killing its process).

Performance wise there are so many parameters involved (overhead of try/catch vs monitor, the frequency your code is run at etc.) that you'd have to benchmark for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use try/catch only in situations where throwing of error is normal behaviour e.g. say, `lookup_value/1` in `grpoc` (it throws badarg if key is not registered, while I'd expect and prefer to get `undefined` instead).

That's Erlang philosophy as I understand it: you should program for good case and not try to be defensive too much i.e. there are some cases where you should care while in most cases just let it crash.